# Aggregation of fields in use in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I want to make a **single query** which will tell me which fields in my mapping are in use for a specific user. This seems like something you should be able to do with aggregation but I'm drawing a blank as to how.

So if my mapping contains `user`, `field1`, `field2` and `field3`. I'd like to know which of these actually appear in the documents with a given user. I was expecting something like `field1` is used in 12 documents, `field2` in 20 documents, and `field3` in 5 documents for user `x`.

Comment: So basically, a `terms` aggregation for the field `user`, over that a `filters` aggregation for each field. That should give you `user/{field1:count, field2:count, field3:count}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well the requirement, this should do it:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "user": {
        "value": "x"
      }
    }
  }, 
  "aggs": {
    "field1_count": {
      "filter": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "field1"
        }
      }
    },
    "field2_count": {
      "filter": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "field2"
        }
      }
    },
    "field3_count": {
      "filter": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "field3"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```